# How to calculate position on a circle with a certain angle?

Tags: java, android, math, geometry

I'm trying to figure out how I could be able to calculate coordinates on a circle. For simplicity I made some images.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1F2y.png]

That's the start with information I have. Now I need to calculate the new coordinates when for example the circle would turn 90 degrees to the right. Just like the next image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckopK.png]

I need to calculate the coordinates of the new red dot. (I also need this with different degrees such as 20 degrees).

To do this my plan was to do the following:

- Calculate the distance between the two points
- Calculate the degree between the north (up) and the given point
- Calculate the new location with the degree (from a step back) + the degrees it needs to turn (in the images 90 degrees).

My first step is:

```
distance = Math.sqrt((point1.x-point2.x)*(point1.x-point2.x) + (point1.y-point2.y)*(point1.y-point2.y))
```

The part to calculate the new degrees is:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(targetPt.y - centerPt.y, targetPt.x - centerPt.x);
theta += Math.PI/2.0;
```

And the last part to calculate the new location would be:

```
double x = mMiddleView.getX() + distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
double y = mMiddleView.getY() + distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta));
```

However when I do these calculations with for example 0 degrees it still returns another value than the original coordinates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit for Philipp Jahoda:

My values are:

```
distance +- 70, currentDegree = 0.
PointF point = new PointF((float)mMiddleView.getX(), (float)mMiddleView.getY());
PointF point2 = getPosition(point, (float) distance, currentDegree);
```

and my results are:

```
center: PointF(490.0, 728.0) radius: 78.0 angle: 0.0
new point: PointF(568.0, 728.0)
```

As you can see, the degree is 0 so the point is not supposed to turn. It should keep the 490, 728 coordinates but it does not keep those.

Comment: Why can't you work in polar coordinates the entire time? Convert to Cartesian just for the display stage.

Comment: Otherwise, this link might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: You are using `x` and `y` the same. Be careful that `x` is increasing rightward while `y` is increasing downward so your `targetPt.y - centerPt.y` part should be the opposite among other things

Comment: Another issue is `theta += Math.PI/2.0;` that this part rotates towards the opposite direction of that in your picture. Use `theta -= Math.PI/2.0;` instead

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thats how:

```
private PointF getPosition(PointF center, float radius, float angle) {

    PointF p = new PointF((float) (center.x + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))),
    (float) (center.y + radius* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));

    return p;
}
```

This method **calculates the position** around the center of a circle (center of your view) depending on radius and angle. Angle in degrees.

The returned `PointF` will contain the x- and y-coordinate of the calculated position.

**Be aware that 0 degrees is at the very east position of the circle, 270 degrees is in the very north position of the circle:**

[image]

So if the center of your view is at x: 100, y: 100 and you calculate the position with an angle of 0 degrees and a radius of 50, the result will be x: 150, y: 100

If you use angle 90 degrees and radius 50, the result will be x: 100, y: 150

It is used [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/Utils.java#L465-L468) in my charting libary, and it works.

Comment: I tried this, but encountered a problem. I am putting my values up in the top post because I can't put code in the comments.

Comment: Have a look at my update. 0 degrees is in the east of the circle. So your calculation is correct.

Comment: Not yet, something else came up which I needed to do. Will report later about it because I will continue on it later today.

Comment: Okay, I looked into it a bit and it works partially. How it calculates the coordinates works good but there's a problem. It only stays in the top-right of the circle. I pasted my results (with x,y, radius, angle) in this pastebin: -removed- It's supposed to go all around instead of only the top-right part, if that could be fixed it would be perfect. EDIT: Nevermind that. It does work now, now to fix my own bugs. Thanks for this!

Comment: @PhilippJahoda: what should i do if 0 degrees is s in the very north position and 90 degree is at the very east position of the circle and same as 180 at very south and so on.., should i do minus 90 for angle grater than 90 and plus 270 for angle less than 90 ?

Comment: How to edit the max value from 360 to some other value lets say 500

Answer (score 0):

This need some mathematics here. You need to know if two lines are perpendicular to each other, The multiplication of those two lines gradient should equals to `-1`.

Then

```
m1=(770-500)/(540-400)=27/14
```

same way

```
m2=(y-770)/(x-540)
```

`(x,y)` is the point you want to find.

Now

```
m1*m2=-1
```

Now we got one equation. You need another since there are two variable needs to find

You can get another by considering the radius of the circle.

```
r=sqrt((540-400)^2+(770-500)^2)
```

Same way

```
r=sqrl((x-540)^2+(y-770)^2)
```

Now you got two equation and only needs to solve. This will give you two set of coordinates. Since there can be `-90` and `90` degrees.

Answer (score 0):

One elegant way to accomplish this is using complex numbers, available for example [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html).

In pseudo-code:

```
z = (x_old + I*y_old)*exp(I*angle);
x_new = real(z);
y_new = imag(z);
```

NOTE: the rotation `angle` needs to be in radians.
NOTE2: this assumes a circle centred at (0,0). Just add a shift if the center is not there.