# How to draw a line that connects two circle outlines without trig functions?

Tags: drawing, line, geometry

How to calculate endpoints of the shortest line connecting two circles without using the trig functions?

[Two circles and a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fugJW.png)

Comment: Please refer to the faq to learn how to ask a good question on this site.

Comment: get a point on the circumference of the circles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929820/how-to-calculate-position-on-a-circle-with-a-certain-angle and then draw a line.  But your question does not specify how the circles are drawn on the screen with respect to the each other and with respect to the screen.

Comment: Raghunandan, link you provided is not really what I asked. It's too complicated to do my task that way. The answer provided by alex looks simpler and it seams to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle explained below is quite intuitive - instead of analyzing two-dimensional task we divide it in two one-dimensional operations. To be precise we take apart x and y coordinate values for known circle centers and calculate values separately. We calculate new x' and y' only knowing the distance between circle centers and the proportions of radii of said circles to the distance between centers.

```
(x1 , y1 ), (x2 , y2 ), r1, r2 - known values
(x1', y1'), (x2', y2') - values we are looking for
```

And all you need to calculate the values we are looking for are following operations:

```
ΔY = y2 - y1           
ΔX = x2 - x1  
L = √(ΔX² + ΔY²)
r1L = r1 / L
r2L = r2 / L  
y1' = y1 + ΔY * r1L 
y2' = y2 - ΔY * r2L 
x1' = x1 + ΔX * r1L 
x2' = x2 - ΔX * r2L
```

And you get *(x1', y1')* and *(x2', y2')*

---

*The theory behind this calculation is as follows...*

Having two circles with their radii r1 and r2 and center coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) we need to find points (x1', y1') and (x2', y2') at which the line connecting two centers intersects the circles.

[image: Circles and projections onto axes]

Having centers of the two circles (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) we calculate ΔX and ΔY which will be used later twice.

```
ΔY = y2 - y1            It is worth noting here that Δ can
ΔX = x2 - x1            be negative if x1 > x2 or y1 > y2
```

First to calculate distance between the centers using Pythagoras theorem:

```
L = √(ΔX² + ΔY²)
```

And second time to calculate the offsets using the ratios of the radii to the L (the length of the whole line).

Now looking at the plot below we see that we have a trapezoid with one of the sides being the y axis and the other the line connecting circles' centers.

[image: First trapezoid]

We know that first circle radius is r1 and the length between centers is L. 
We also know that line paralel to the base line splitting trapezoid splits its sides with the same ratios.
Because we know the distance L and the radius r1 we can calculate the ratio.

```
r1L = r1 / L
```

Now we can use this ratio to get the point (0, y2').

```
y1' = y1 + ΔY * r1L
```

So now we have got the y component of (x1', y1') coordinate. We do similarly with y2'.

```
r2L = r2 / L
y2' = y2 - ΔY * r2L
```

To get x1' and x2' we use the x axis to form the other trapezoid and similarly repeat steps shown above.

[image: Second trapezoid]

```
x1' = x1 + ΔX * r1L 
x2' = x2 - ΔX * r2L
```

As a result we end up with new endpoints (x1', y1') and (x2', y2').

It has to be noted that x1' and y1' values are calculated by adding to them but x2' and y2' values are calculated by subtracting from them. It is so because we initially assume that (x1, y1) is closer to the center coordinate (0, 0), i.e. `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2`, in `ΔY = y2 - y1` and `ΔX = x2 - x1`.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a line between the center of the two circles. Find the points where that line intersects the circles. Your line is between those two points.

[image: Line between circles]

Call the centers of the two circles (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).

```
ΔY = y2-y1   \___ for the whole line (blue-red-blue)
ΔX = x2-x1   /
```

The length of the line between the circle centers is:

```
L = √(ΔX² + ΔY²)
```

Using the each circle's radius, r, you can compute the Δy and Δx from the center to the other end of the blue line:

```
Δx = r/L ΔX
Δy = r/L ΔY
```

So the points are (x1+Δx, y1+Δy) and similarly for the other blue line.
Now you have the two endpoints of the red line.

Now, on each end you need a line (the blue part) whose length is equal to the radius of the relevant circle.  At this point you can forget about the circles!